# Trim Cell Contents to Certain Lenght with Scientific Numbers

Tags: excel, char, trim, scientific-notation, vba

I have a column of numbers that I need to keep as numbers but limit the length to 20 characters.

```
Sub casecheck()

Dim myString As String
Dim newString As String
Dim char As Variant

'replace all special characters with nothing
Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,.,#,$,%,^,&,-,(,),{,[,],},/,\, "

For i = 2 To trans

myString = Worksheets("Data Input").Cells(i, 10).Value
newString = myString
For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
newString = Replace(newString, char, "")
Worksheets("ExpertPay Feed").Cells(i, 3).Value = newString
Worksheets("ExpertPay Feed").Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "0"
Next
Next i

'trim length down to 20 characters

For i = 2 To trans
Worksheets("ExpertPay Feed").Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Worksheets("ExpertPay Feed").Cells(i, 3).Value, 20)
Next i


End Sub
```

My code works really well, except when I have numbers that are very long.  For example:

This original number: 1.31137E+17 turns into 13113690920150400000000000000000
 and I can't seem to trim off all the extra zeroes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
Function TrimTrailingZeroes(BigNumber As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Len(BigNumber) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(BigNumber, i, 1) <> "0" Then
            TrimTrailingZeroes = Left(BigNumber, i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    TrimTrailingZeroes = BigNumber
End Function
```

Sometimes in can be an easy way out treating numbers as text.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it still doesn't work.  I am getting the same thing :(